# create javascript object with key and value from variables

Tags: javascript

I've been reading up on javascript and I this site has helped me quite a lot. My goal is to create a javascript object with the "key, value" pair coming from variables. For starters I am trying to create the following javascript object,
If I create like this:

```
    var tester = {
        person : "Sarah",
        friends : ["Tom", "Nils"],
        parents : ["Sandra", "Peter"]
    };
```

That works fine. However trying a different approach:

```
var tester = {};
var person = "Sarah";
var friendsArr = ["Tom", "Nils"];
var parentsArr = ["Sandra", "Peter"];

tester[person] = person;
tester[friends] = friendsArr;
tester[parents] = parentsArr;
```

That doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
tester['person'] = person;
tester['friends'] = friendsArr;
tester['parents'] = parentsArr;
```

or alternatively:

```
tester.person = person;
tester.friends = friendsArr;
tester.parents = parentsArr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot notation to assign the object keys.

```
var tester = {};
var person = "Sarah";
var friendsArr = ["Tom", "Nils"];
var parentsArr = ["Sandra", "Peter"];

tester.person = person;
tester.friends = friendsArr;
tester.parents = parentsArr
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to defined the property of the object as an array

Here is your answer

```
var tester = {};
var person = "Sarah";
var friendsArr = ["Tom", "Nils"];
var parentsArr = ["Sandra", "Peter"];

tester.person = person;
tester.friends = [];
tester.parents = [];
tester.friends = friendsArr;
tester.parents = parentsArr
```

One thing i need to suggest to all javascript developers.You need to be very carefull while working with arrays.

If you assign a array directly for eg :-tester.friends = friendsArr
This will create a reference to friendsArr Object so any change in 
tester.friends will ultimate cause an change in friendsArr
Best way is to create a new array instance and push variable inside.